# HOW can get update to c# application from active directory user and user group updates

Tags: c#, active-directory, development-environment

i'm working on C# application working with active directory.

1. my application add active directory group to my system and map feature with user group
   02.then user login to the system will check with active directory which group in this user in the active directory and grant my application permission.

my problem is after adding AD usergroup my system AD admin add nested group to AD  (already added )group to my system, i can't query using user name this nested group with group with associate.

Comment: Can you show some code?  Which line is failing to produce the expected results?